# Retrieve facebook uses who have posted a url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm interesting using the FB API to query for which users have shared a certain URL.  Shared, not liked.

So starting with something like http://cnn.com, I'd love to get the IDs or at least names of users who have shared the link.

I realize that many FB posts are private to the user's network, but some are public like on a fan page.

Reading through the documentation, I couldn't find a way to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. You can get the share count, but not a list of users.

Comment: Yea I don't think its possible as well, since soon, posts on Pages will not be publicly available in the API. Now the only stream you can rely on is the Pulic Posts on user's timeline which you can access from the /search feature

Comment: that was my fear.  alright thanks guys